# .then not waiting until promise completion

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, file-io, promise

I have a main menu function calling two modules. The first gets data and writes it to a file. The second opens that file and runs tests on it. I cannot for the life of me get the second function to wait until the first has completed and created the necessary file. Err is always file does not exist. Both files work as intended separately and run separate in command line. In short, I'm trying to do:

1. userinput (in the main menu with the code below)
2. User input used to create files (getstock.main which is an imported module which returns 1)
3. Open file and run tests on it (test1.main which is an imported module)

```js
const test1 = require('./daytrade2.js');
const getstock = require('./yahoodatapuller2.js');
const process = require('process'); 
var args = process.argv; 
let domefirst=function(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    var promisefinished=0;
    promisefinished= getstock.main(args[2])
    if(promisefinished)
    {
        resolve(1)
      }
})}

domefirst().then((result)=>{if(result)
  {test1.main(args[2],args[3])}
}).catch((err)=>{console.log(err)})
```

further ill add that running the following yields the same error

```js
domefirst().then(()=>{test1.main(args[2],args[3])
}).catch((err)=>{console.log(err)})
```

further, this is getstock

```
exports.main= function(stocksym){
//var stocksym='AAPL';
const https= require('https');
var lockup=[];
fs =require('fs')
var open=[];
var close=[];
var high=[];
var low=[];
var dd=[];
var mm=[];
var yy=[];
var wkday=[];
var timestamps=[];
var volume=[];


modules = [
   'assetProfile',//0
   'summaryProfile',
   'summaryDetail',//2
   'esgScores',
   'price',//4
   'incomeStatementHistory',//6
   'incomeStatementHistoryQuarterly',
   'balanceSheetHistory',//8
   'balanceSheetHistoryQuarterly',
   'cashflowStatementHistory',
   'cashflowStatementHistoryQuarterly',
   'defaultKeyStatistics',
   'financialData',
   'calendarEvents',
   'secFilings',
   'recommendationTrend',
   'upgradeDowngradeHistory',
   'institutionOwnership',
   'fundOwnership',
   'majorDirectHolders',
   'majorHoldersBreakdown',
   'insiderTransactions',
   'insiderHolders',
   'netSharePurchaseActivity',
   'earnings',
   'earningsHistory',
   'earningsTrend',
   'industryTrend',
   'indexTrend',
   'sectorTrend' ]
    
function spacer(data){

    data=JSON.stringify(data)
    for (i=0; i<data.length;i++)
    {
        if (data[i]==',')
        
        {
            data.splice(i,0,'\n')
        }
    }
    return JSON.parse(data);
}
    

function rounder(num){

    num=Math.round((num + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
    return num;
}
var calltime=0;
var before='';
var after='';
var fileout= function(summary){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    var promisedone= false;

    calltime+=1;
    var json= JSON.stringify(summary)
    var fname=stocksym+'.json'
    switch(calltime){
        case 1:
        before= '{"dd":';
        after= ',\n';
        break;
        case 2:
        before= '"mm":';
        after= ',\n';
        break;
        case 3:
        before= '"yy":';
        after=',\n';
        break;
        case 4:
        before= '"wkday":';
        after=',\n';
        break;
        case 5:
        before= '"open":';
        after=',\n';
        break;
        case 6:
        before= '"close":';
        after=',\n';
        break;
        case 7:
        before= '"high":';
        after=',\n';
        break;
        case 8:
        before= '"low":';
        after=',\n';
        break;
        case 9:
        before= '"volume":';
        after='}\n';
        calltime=0;
        break;
        default:
        console.log('error switch line 114');
    }
    
    
    fs.appendFile(fname,before + json+ after, function(err) { 
        if (err) throw err;
        // if no error
        console.log("Data is appended to file successfully.")
    promisedone= true;
    if(promisedone)
        {
            promisedone=false;
            resolve();
        }

    })
        
    
    })
}
    
var p1='1595203200';//startdate unix (usually 0)
var p2='1596039048';//enddate
var int='1d'; // "1d","5d","1mo","3mo","6mo","1y","2y","5y","10y","ytd","max"
var url='https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/'+stocksym+'?symbol='+stocksym+'&period1='+p1+'&period2='+p2+'&interval='+int;
var furl=url;

https.get( furl,
    res => {
        var body= '';
        res.on('data',data=>{
            body+=(data);
            
        })
        
        res.on('end',function(){
        body=JSON.stringify(body);
        body=JSON.parse(body)
        body=JSON.parse(body)
        var d= new Date();

        for(i=0;i<body.chart.result[0].timestamp.length; i++)
        {
            timestamps.push(body.chart.result[0].timestamp[i] *1000)
            d= new Date(timestamps[i])
            
             dd.push(d.getDate());
             mm.push(d.getMonth());
             yy.push(d.getFullYear());
             wkday.push(d.getDay());
             open.push(rounder(body.chart.result[0].indicators.quote[0].open[i]));
             close.push(rounder(body.chart.result[0].indicators.quote[0].close[i]));
             high.push(rounder(body.chart.result[0].indicators.quote[0].high[i]));
             low.push(rounder(body.chart.result[0].indicators.quote[0].low[i]));
             volume.push(body.chart.result[0].indicators.quote[0].volume[i]);
            
        
        
        }
        
        fileout(dd).then(()=>{fileout(mm);
        }).then(()=>{ fileout(yy);
        }).then(()=>{ fileout(wkday);
        }).then(()=>{ fileout(open);
        }).then(()=>{ fileout(close);
        }).then(()=>{ fileout(high);
        }).then(()=>{ fileout(low);
        }).then(()=>{ fileout(volume);
        }).catch((err)=>{console.log(err)})
        

        //console.log(dd + '\n'+mm+'\n'+ yy+ '\n'+wkday+ '\n'+ open + '\n'+ close + '\n'+ high + '\n'+ low + '\n'+ volume)
        
        })
        






    })
    return 1;

}
```

Comment: Please put code in your question, not as an image. See [mre].

Comment: Also provide a description of what getstock does including what it returns.

Comment: We really can't help you without seeing your code.  Questions about code here should always contain your actual code as text, pasted into the question, not as an image, not as an external link.  There are a whole bunch of reasons that this site requires code that is important to understanding the question be pasted into the question as text.

Comment: The problem is `getstock.main(args[2])` - what does this return? If it doesn't return a promise, you need a way to detect when that finishes. As it stands => if `promisedFinished` is not immediately assigned "true", you do not resolve or reject your promise and so it never finishes and you'll never get to `.then()`

Comment: @daddygames I've updated accordingly, also thank you for your help already, I'm new here. If I need getstock.main to return a promise how would I do that since its an exported function

Comment: @jfriend00 see updates thank you

Comment: Please show us the code for `getstock.main(args[2])`.  Nothing in the code you've shown so far is asynchronous and thus there is no need for a promise at all in what you've shown.  So, if `getstock.main()` is asynchronous, then the problem needs to be fixed IN THAT CODE, not in the code you're showing us.

Comment: @jfriend00 getstock has been added. It is long, but really all its doing is retrieving data, parsing what I want, and then printing it to a file in an orderly fashion. I make use of promises at the end to make sure it prints to file in the order i want it to regardless of how long the data is

Comment: `getstock()` does not appear to communicate back in any way when it is done thus the caller has no way to know when it's done.  So you will need to fix it so that it returns a promise that resolves when it's done.  You also don't have any way to communicate back errors either.

Comment: @jfriend00 okay that kind of makes sense, how do i return a promise from an exported function though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getstock()` does not appear to communicate back in any way when it is done thus the caller has no way to know when it's done. So you will need to fix it so that it returns a promise that resolves when it's done. You also don't have any way to communicate back errors either.

> okay that kind of makes sense, how do i return a promise from an exported function though?

It makes no difference whether it's exported or not - it's just a function.  The same way that you built a promise into `fileout()` and return it, you can do that with `getstock.main()`.  Also, you really should not be mixing the use of promises and plain callbacks.  Take all your low level asynchronous operations that don't already return promises and make a wrapper that returns a promise and then use only promise logic for your control flow.

A couple other hints:

1. Make use of `let` and `const`.
2. Stop using `var`.
3. Use the `fs.promises` interface to get `fs` module functions that already use promises.
4. Use something like [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) instead of `https.get()` for promise-based https fetching.
5. Get rid of your `promisedone` variable.  It doesn't seem to be doing anything useful and makes things look more complicated than they are.

Here's a sample rewrite of `fileout()` that uses `fs.promises.appendFile()`, uses a table-lookup instead of a giant `switch()` and switches everything to `const` and `let`:

```
function fileout(summary) {
    const prefixes = [
        '{"dd":', '"mm":', '"yy":', '"wkday":', '"open":', 
        '"close":', '"high":', '"low":', '"volume":', 
    ];
    calltime += 1;
    const json = JSON.stringify(summary);
    const fname = stocksym + '.json';
    const before = prefixes[calltime - 1];
    let after = ',\n';
    if (calltime === prefixes.length) {
        after = '}\n';
        calltime = 0;
    }
    return fs.promises.appendFile(fname, before + json + after);
}
```

You probably should change how the `calltime` variable works too because this is side-effect programming which is not generally a good idea.  Perhaps you should just pass that variable into `fileout()` and have the caller increment it and control it.

The same concepts can be applied to your larger function.

---

Here's an attempt at a larger rewrite to simplify it a lot:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const got = require('got');

exports.main = async function(stocksym) {
    // create initial object that we want to write JSON version of to the file
    const stockData = {
        dd: [],
        mm: [],
        yy: [],
        wkday: [],
        open: [],
        close: [],
        high: [],
        low: [],
        volume: []
    };

    function rounder(num){
        return Math.round((num + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
    }

    // get the stock data
    const p1 = '1595203200'; //startdate unix (usually 0)
    const p2 = '1596039048'; //enddate
    const int = '1d'; // "1d","5d","1mo","3mo","6mo","1y","2y","5y","10y","ytd","max"
    const url = `https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/${stocksym}?symbol=${stocksym}&period1=${p1}&period2=${p2}&interval=${int}`;
    console.log(url);
    const {chart} = await got(url).json();
    const timestamps = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < chart.result[0].timestamp.length; i++) {
        timestamps.push(chart.result[0].timestamp[i] * 1000);
        const d = new Date(timestamps[i])
        stockData.dd.push(d.getDate());
        stockData.mm.push(d.getMonth());
        stockData.yy.push(d.getFullYear());
        stockData.wkday.push(d.getDay());
        stockData.open.push(rounder(chart.result[0].indicators.quote[0].open[i]));
        stockData.close.push(rounder(chart.result[0].indicators.quote[0].close[i]));
        stockData.high.push(rounder(chart.result[0].indicators.quote[0].high[i]));
        stockData.low.push(rounder(chart.result[0].indicators.quote[0].low[i]));
        stockData.volume.push(chart.result[0].indicators.quote[0].volume[i]);
    }

    const fname = stocksym + '.json';
    return fs.promises.writeFile(fname, JSON.stringify(stockData));
}
```

This new version of `getstock.main()` returns a promise that resolves/rejects when done.  The caller can then use that promise to know when everything is done by either using `await` or `.then()` and `.catch()` on that promise.

Comment: @SumSpicyCode - I added a rewrite of your `getstock.main()` function.  This returns a promise that resolves or rejects when done.